# linux: why does piping "find" to "tar" produce a larger tar file than tar by itself?

Tags: linux, find, tar

This is likely easy, but it's unclear to me:

If I tar the whole directory...

```
tar -zcvf all.tar.gz /my/data/output
  --size 1.2 gig
```

If I "du" a search range of files....

```
find /my/data/output -newermt 20220101 -not -newermt 20240101 | du -h 
  --size 1.3 gig
```

But if I then tar the range...

```
 find /my/data/output -newermt 20220101 -not -newermt 20240101 -print0 | tar -zcvf 2022.tar.gz --null -T - 
    --size 3.8 gig
```

Why would "find" produce a bigger tar file than tarring the whole directory without find?

There are files with spaces in the names, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Get lists of files from each archive and compare those lists. I suspect either the smaller archive is missing files (maybe hidden files?) or that the larger archive is converting symbolic links to files/directories.